# Idiomatic test for file/directory creation

Tags: r, testthat

Say I have a function that creates a directory and file:

```
foo <- function(){
  dir.create("bar")
  file.create("./bar/myfile.txt")
}
```

I need to test that the function does its job. I can do this with `expect_true` from the `testthat` package, like so:

```
test_that("File & directory are created",{
  foo()
  expect_true(file.exists("./bar/myfile.txt"))  
})
```

This seems to work okay, but my question is what is the idiomatic way of testing for file/directory creation using `testthat`? There are specific functions for other side effects (e.g., `expect_output`), but I haven't found an equivalent for files/directories.

Comment: Some ideas : https://rdrr.io/github/johnmyleswhite/ProjectTemplate/src/tests/testthat/test-create.R

Comment: @Waldi Thanks for the link! The approaches there look similar to my approach (e.g., `expect_true` wrapping `file.exists`, but of course their approach is much better fleshed out). So, your point is that there isn't a standard `testthat` approach, but rather we should use a roll-your-own approach?

Comment: AFAIK, there are no specific `testthat` functions for files/directory creation. You might also have a look at some run-time check packages like [assertive.files](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/assertive.files/README.html)